# Saving image to camera roll iOS works in simulator but not on phone

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, screenshot

I'm using the following code to save a screenshot from a Cocos2d layer to the camera roll..

```
    -(void) takeScreenshot {

    [self turnAllNotesBlack];

    CCScene *scene = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene];
    CCNode *n = [scene.children objectAtIndex:0];
    UIImage *img = [self screenshotWithStartNode:n];
    //NSParameterAssert(img);
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img,
                                   self,
                                   @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                   nil);

    [self resetIlluminatedNotes];

    }

-(void)image:(UIImage *)image
finishedSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
 contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: @"Save failed"
                              message: @"Failed to save image"
                              delegate: nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

It works fine on the simulator, but when I run it on my phone, it calls the error method, and no picture is saved.

Does anyone know why this is?

Carl

Comment: It might help NSLog the error and add that to the question.

Comment: Here's the error NSLog: Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain Code=-3310 "Data unavailable" UserInfo=0x1d58a1b0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Launch the Photos application, NSUnderlyingError=0x1e8825f0 "Data unavailable", NSLocalizedDescription=Data unavailable}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahh the answer lies in the phone itself..

I had to go to 'Settings -> Privacy -> Photos' and enable photos for my new App..

Comment: nice.   googling that error worked, right?  you can mark your own answer correct.

Comment: yeah I googled the error.. I had to learn how to NSLog an error message too, I'd never done that before.. So thanks for putting me on the right track :-)

Comment: @CarlosTheJackal  Tick your answer , if it got answer